# search comma separated values in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a bit of a problem running a select query on a database. Some of the data is held as a list of comma separated values, an example:

Table: **example_tbl**

```
| Id | standardid | subjectid  |
| 1  | 1,2,3    |  8,10,3  |
| 2  | 7,6,12   |  18,19,2 |
| 3  | 10,11,12 |  4,3,7   |
```

And an example of the kind of thing I am trying to run:

```
select * from table where standardid in (7,10) and subjectid in (2,3,4)
select * from table  where FIND_IN_SET(7,10,standardid)  and FIND_IN_SET(2,3,4,subjectid)
```

Thanks in advance for anything you can tell me.

Comment: So - is it `standardid` or `standard`?

Comment: Note that searching this type of table will be very slow if the table is large. comma-separated values aren't indexed in any way that makes searching for items efficient.

Answer (score 1):

comma separated values in a database are inherently problematic and inefficient, and it is far, far better to normalise your database design; but if you check the syntax for [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) it looks for a single value in the set, not matches several values in the set.

To use it for multiple values, you need to use the function several times:

```
select * from table
 where (FIND_IN_SET(7,standardid)
     OR FIND_IN_SET(10,standardid))
   and (FIND_IN_SET(2,subjectid)
     OR FIND_IN_SET(3,subjectid)
     OR FIND_IN_SET(4,subjectid))
```

Comment: in dynamic way like $a= "2,3,4"

Comment: You'd have to split $a into an array of individual values, and build your query for each value in that array

Comment: I am getting values from form post sir.

Comment: Then you build your query by iterating over the relevant values in $_POST... I've shown you what the query should look like.... I've also recommended that you normalise your database properly